# Resources for studying different set theories

Tags: set-theory, book-recommendation, foundations

Ok so lately I have been fascinated about general structure of mathematics and I have read some books on set theory.

I have gone through the Endertons introductory book on set theory which operates in ZFC,but I have understood that use of classes simplifies many things,that is how I got to know about NBG set theory.

Lately I have heard of many other set theories such as Morse-Kelly ,ZF,Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

I would like to get some resources which explain these theories and how they relate to one another,and what are the pros and cons of each theory.

Thanks in advance